# RSS2 Feed with two CDATA sections

Tags: rss, feed

**Why my feed description is breaking like this?** It occurs only on some posts, but the others are echoed perfectly in *like* a single `<p>`.

[image: broken feed description]

The code for my feed is that simple:

```
<description><![CDATA[<?php the_content(); ?>]]></description>
```

And I inspected the particular post and found nothing:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">হেফাজতে ইসলামী বাংলাদেশ’র সমাবেশে বিভিন্ন এলাকা থেকে দলে দলে কর্মী-সমর্থকরা এসে যোগ দিচ্ছে। আর ক্ষুধার্ত-তৃষ্ণার্র্ত কর্মী-সমর্থকদের জন্য সমাবেশে কিছুক্ষণ পর পর পানি, ক্ষীরা, তরমুজ, কমলা, আপেল থেকে শুরু করে বিরিয়ানি পর্যন্ত আসছে।</p>
```

It's broken on the second line where the glyph "ক্ষুধার্ত-তৃষ্ণার্র্ত" presents.

For a critical scrutiny, I guess, 'ক্ষ' is a joint-glyph (*যুক্তাক্ষর*) in Bangla a mixture of two character - that may cause a break there. But I inspected other similar post where I found plain character.

[image: broken feed description 2]

The line was broken here within: "চট্টগ্রাম থেকে ঢাকা অভিমুখে লংমার্চে".

As though they are broken, it's producing two `<![CDATA[ texts here ]]>` within a single `<description>` tag. It's not good for an apps developer to fetch the whole description dynamically.

I found nothing in between the broken words, or characters. And in the first example the line is broken within a single word, but in second one it's broken after a complete word.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is it `the_content()` and not `the_content_rss()`?

Comment: Thanks. `the_content_rss();` solved most of them, but till in some feeds, the description is broken. In the meantime, I tried, `get_the_content();` - same result. Some of them are broken. :(

Comment: `the_content_rss()` is deprecated. Is using it safe, or not?

Comment: Then use `the_content_feed()` instead.